# How to perform differential or incremental snapshot and how it works?

Tags: elasticsearch, backup, snapshot

I want to know that how can I take differential snapshots in ElasticSearch and also how it works?

We received around 30 GB of data monthly in all indices of ElasticSearch. Few indices get update daily and few indices data get purge after certain retention days. So I was thinking to go with incremental snapshot so that it will not take time and only modified data will get into a snapshot. But I don't know how it works and will it be feasible for my case?

Could you please help me to design a snapshot process so that it can work permanently and will not be impacted with time.

**ElasticSearch Version: 6.2.4**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All snapshots to a single repository are incremental. You will not have to do anything specifically to take differential snapshots. If you just take snapshots to the same repository, each snapshot will try to reuse as much data as possible from prior snapshots automatically.

For more details:

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/feasible-solution-of-snapshot-for-30-gb-and-increasing-every-day-data/217568/3